# Polymer 1.X - Complex observer not firing

Tags: javascript, polymer, observers

I have a complex observer on all object's subproperties, but it never trigger, I don't understand why..

```js
//Declaration's property
requirement: {
    type:Object,
    value: {
        allLoaded: false,
        tagsLoaded: false
    }
},

//Complex observer
observers: [
  'requirementChanged(requirement.*)'
],

//Observer definition
requirementChanged: function(val){
    console.log('obs : ', this.requirement, val);//Just to see what's in there
},

//The action that should trigger the observer 
if(res.length > 0)
{
    this.sharedInfo.assetTags = res;
    this.set('requirement.tagsLoaded', true);
    this.notifyPath('requirement.tagsLoaded');
}
```

Thank you all, have a nice day

Answer (score 2):

Your property declaration is setup such a way that its effectively `non-notifying`.

You'll have to set `notify` on the property declaration for Polymer to propagate observable change triggers.
From Polymer 1.x documentation -

> notify - A notifying property supports upward data flow. By default,
>   properties are non-notifying, and don't support upward data flow.

Try changing the property declaration to -

```
//Declaration's property
requirement: {
    type:Object,
    value: {
        allLoaded: false,
        tagsLoaded: false
    },
    notify: true
}
```

Here is further read up on [Observable and Unobservable changes](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-system#observable-changes)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are initialising your property wrong.

> When initializing a property to an object or array value, use a function to ensure that each element gets its own copy of the value, rather than having an object or array shared across all instances of the element.

Here is link to the Polymer documentation where it is explained in detail. 
[Configuring default property values](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties)

Try this in your example

```
requirement: {
  type:Object,
  value: function() {
    return {
      allLoaded: false,
      tagsLoaded: false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: Mhm the only thing I could imagine is that you never actually change the property?! Are you sure your if statement is executed ?!

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote should work. Worst case scenario, write your observer like this:

```
observers: [
  'requirementChanged(requirement.allLoaded, requirement.tagsLoaded)'
],
```